# Weird: For loop returns last iteration under certain conditions

Tags: java, android, for-loop

There is a weird problem I am facing. Whenever I update my array of objects by say adding an extra object so that the size is 5, my for loop changes its behavior. And when i revert it, it goes back to normal. Here is my code

```
String[] a = new String[4];
    a[0] = "EVENT 1";
    a[1] = "EVENT 2";
    a[2] = "EVENT 3";
    a[3] = "EVENT 4";

    LatLng[] b = new LatLng[4];
    b[0] = new LatLng(32.546586510595404, -80.70999909192324);
    b[1] = new LatLng(32.54606196179351, -80.71023747324944);
    b[2] = new LatLng(32.54620949145382, -80.70962257683277);
    b[3] = new LatLng(32.494091, -80.739474);
```

I then add the objects to a list by a for loop (that acts correctly) and then i have another for loop that retrieves these objects from a getter setter class

```
for(int i = 0; i <= event.size(); i++) {
            latB = event.get(i).getmLatLng().latitude;
            lngB = event.get(i).getmLatLng().longitude; }
```

So the behavior of the for loop goes from normal to only retrieving the last iteration for the appointed number of times. I have been looking for days on what exactly is causing the problem but i dont see anything wrong, especially since when i revert the arrays back to the way they were, the problem ceases. What is causing this problem?

***EDIT****

Okay so this is the code that goes in between the first two. Here is the event class that creates Event Objects

```
public class Event{
public LatLng mLatLng;

public Event()
{

}
public Event(String id, LatLng latlng)
 {
        mLatLng = latlng;
        mId = id;


 }



public void setmLatLng(LatLng latLng)
{
    this.mLatLng = latLng;
}

public LatLng getmLatLng()
{
    return this.mLatLng;
}}
```

Then in the same activity as before, I add those events to a list and store the list in an sql Lite database

```
int TOTALEVENTS = a.length-1;



    for(int i = 0; i <= TOTALEVENTS; i++)
    {

        EVENTS.add(i, new Event(new String(EVENTNAME[i]), EVENTLOCATION[i]));

    } db.addEvents(EVENTS);
```

Then I go to the code that I had before and the SQL Lite Database returns the stored list

```
List<Event> event = new ArrayList<Event>();
        event = db.getEvents();
```

Comment: Please describe the problem in more detail. What does "only retrieving the last iteration for the appointed number of times" mean?

Comment: I mean that when the for loop runs, for each time it runs it only returns the last value. Say i have the loop running through an array of strings and the last value in that array is "Jim". For each time the array runs, its putting "JIM" as the value for i when thats not the case.

Comment: Try removing all the records from the table before you run the code again: `db.delete(TABLE, null, null);`

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalles the app which from my understanding deletes the db.

Comment: ................@alfasin

Comment: .............@Elliott Frisch

Comment: Yes it deletes the DB. You can try and post the code of `db.getEvents();` but other then that, the only way to find the root of this issue will be to either run with a debugger or add some debug-printings to logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how it works at all since you're using `<=` in the for loop while you should be using `<`:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= event.size(); i++)
```

should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < event.size(); i++)
```

Further, you didn't show us important part of the code: you're using `event.get(i)...` - the `get()` is a list annotation - not an array. That means that you're doing some kind of "translation" from array to the object which is called `event` in your code. How does this translation performed ? the bug could be there as well.

Comment: I have tried that and i have edited and rephrased my code many times but the problem doesnt go away. Also, like I mentioned, the code works completely fine when the object arrays are not changed. but when I change the object arrays by increasing its size, then it doesnt work correctly

Comment: Well I don't think there is anything wrong with the db code.  Everything worked just fine when the array was less the 3. I'll try the debugger. Thanks. @alfasin

Comment: Pro tip: "I don't think there is anything wrong with..." => that's usually where bugs hide ;)

Comment: I understand. @alfasin but i'm lost at why the code works when the array is less than three? All the db does is moves the Cursor to next and get the values until it reaches no value.

Answer (score 0):

So I have not fixed this problem but I have found a solid work around. I converted all of my arrays to lists. However the root of the problem after I debugged it was getting the events from the sqllite db. The events were being stored correctly but not retrieved correctly for some very, very strange reason. And to add to the mystery of this bug, the problem was with the number 3. If the size of the lists or array was equal to 4, the events would not be retrieved correctly resulting in the bug. So after converting the arrays to lists and increasing the size of the lists, the bug ceased.